# Redux: dispatching an action multiple times results to too many api requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reducers

Using an api for anime called Jikan, I'm trying to display promo thumbnails of new anime shows.
I'm using two api calls, one to get the new anime shows:

```
export const get_new_anime = () =>
  `${base_url}search/anime?q&order_by=score&status=airing&sort=desc`;
```

and one for getting the videos (containing promos) of anime by getting its `id`.

```
export const get_news = (anime_id) => `${base_url}anime/${anime_id}/videos`;
```

In my home page, here I am mapping the shows, returning a component for each anime:

```
<Promos>
{new.map((anime, index) => (
<Anime key={anime.mal_id} index={index}></Anime>))}
</Promos>
```

And for each Anime component, I have a `useEffect` which uses `useDispatch` for every new `id`

```
const Anime = ({ id, index }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const loadDetailHandler = () => {
    //  eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    dispatch(loadDetail(id));

  useEffect(() => {
    loadDetailHandler(id);
  }, [id]); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

  const promo = useSelector((state) => state.detail.promo);

  const isLoading = useSelector((state) => state.detail.isLoading);

  return (
    <PromoBox
      style={
        !isLoading
          ? { backgroundImage: `url("${promo[index][0].image_url}")` }
          : null
            }
     ></PromoBox>);
    };
```

Here is how my `promoReducer` looks like:

```
const initState = {
  promo: [],
  isLoading: true,
};

const promoReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOADING_PROMO":
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
      };
    case "GET_DETAIL":
     

      return {
        ...state,

        promo: [...state.promo, action.payload.promo], 
        
        isLoading: false,
        
      };

    default:
      return { ...state };
  }
};

export default promoReducer;
```

and here is the `promoAction`:

```
export const loadPromo = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: "LOADING_PROMO",
  });

  const promoData = await axios.get(get_promos(id));
 
  dispatch({
    type: "GET_DETAIL",
    payload: {  
      promo: promoData.data.promo,
    },
  });
};
```

While it does return the promo data as the action is dispatched, the problem is that in some instances of dispatching, no data is returned. Here is a screenshot from redux devtools to show what I mean:

[image]

and I was trying to get the promos of all the new anime, in which I was expecting to get 50 results of promo data. In devtools, you can see I only got 9 of them. This is followed by an error 429 (too many requests):
[image]

How can I resolve this issue? And is there a better way to do this, because this seems like bad practice:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems that you're limited by the api itself and it's threshold for the number of request per unit of time. There should probably be a request that allows you to pass multiple anime ids to get request in order to avoid requesting details for each anime individually.